# D3 Zoomable Circle Packing throws NaN erros

Tags: d3.js

I've constructed a D3 visualization that was working on my local machine. However, now i've exported to my server, the code breaks and throws several errors:

```
Error: invalid value for <circle> attribute transform="translate"(NaN,NaN)"
Error: invalid value for <text> attribute transform="translate"(NaN,NaN)"
Error: invalid value for <circle> attribute r="NaN"
```

I've had these errors before with similar code and was able to solve them. However, i cannot grasp what is going wrong. Any suggestions? Thanx!

```
    function drawBubbles() {
    var margin = 20,
        diameter = 740;  

    var color = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([-1, 10])
        .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
        .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);  

    var pack = d3.layout.pack()
        .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
        .value(function (d) { return d.size; })  

    var svg = d3.select("form").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 1280)
        .attr("height", 800)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

    d3.json("../Resources/output.json", function (error, root) {
        if (error) throw error;

    var focus = root,
            nodes = pack.nodes(root),
            view;

        var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(nodes)
          .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", function (d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
            .style("fill", function (d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
            .on("click", function (d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

        var text = svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(nodes)
          .enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .style("fill-opacity", function (d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
            .style("display", function (d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
            .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

        var node = svg.selectAll("circle,text");

        d3.select("form")
            .on("click", function () { zoom(root); });

        zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);

        function zoom(d) {
            var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

            var transition = d3.transition()
                .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
                .tween("zoom", function (d) {
                    var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
                     return function (t) { zoomTo(i(t),d); };
                 });

            transition.selectAll("text")
              .filter(function (d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
                 .style("fill-opacity", function (d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
                 .each("start", function (d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
                 .each("end", function (d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
         }

         function zoomTo(v) {
             var k = diameter / v[2]; view = v;
             console.log(d.x)
             console.log(d.y)
             console.log(d.r)
             console.log(k)
             node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
             circle.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; });
         }
     });

     d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this issue - although most browsers seemed to treat NaN as zero and so not complain, but Chrome wasn't happy at all.

For me I found the packed nodes collection returned from the packer had NaNs for zero value items passed in (which my data could contain).  I just looped all the nodes after the pack call and set them to zero.  Something like this should do it (it should probably be a recursive call to avoid duplication, but you get the idea!)...

```
// Replace any zero value items with zero x/y/r values
nodes.forEach( function (currNode) {
  if (!currNode.count) {
    currNode.x = 0;
    currNode.y = 0;
    currNode.r = 0;
    currNode.children.forEach( function (currChild) {
      if (!currChild.count) {
        currChild.x = 0;
        currChild.y = 0;
        currChild.r = 0;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanx for the reply! Eventually, i overlooked an important thing that led to all those errors. The site contains multiple visualizations, all using D3 and the same JSON file as this JSON file dynamically is generated. This eventually was the bottleneck (the JSON file wasn't updated properly ..). Thanx for the help though!